# Creating a door: scale vertex group independently

Tags: vertex-groups, scale

Please let me know if this is the correct question to ask and not an XY problem: Basically I am trying to create a door with dynamic height and width.

Bellow is my attempt: I'm creating an amateur with 6 bones, H_BOT, H_MID, H_TOP in order to scale the door vertically (scaling inheritance of bones are off), the same with L_LEFT, L_MID and L_RIGHT.

[image: edit]

When I have only three bone by one axis (e.g. H_BOT, H_MID and H_TOP) I can scale only the middle part of the door, leaving the to bars on top and bottom with their height

The moment I add more bones of the other axis, the mesh will be distorted, affected by other bones.

My guess is that the weight of the vertex group are normalised despite being displayed as 1, so the scale ratio applied to them are only 1/4.

[image: pose]

Thank you per advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it depends on what you make it for, it may be easier to use shape keys instead and control them via drivers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @unwave, I will study your solution and mark the answer as accepted. One question though: is it feasible to implement with a more complex door. Like with two more bars (horizontal and vertical) and four panels instead of just one? I guess we will need to constrain the panels to have the same dimension?

Comment: I guess the question is going to lose traction I will not get any more answer. Thank you again @unwave

Comment: @QuangLinhLe Can you specify the purpose? Is your door is some kind of character, which sometimes needs to deform like this: https://tenor.com/view/pip-boy-fallout-dodge-fallout4-fallout3-gif-10665428 Then, maybe, it is a good idea to control it via deforming bones or a lattice or a separate deforming mesh. But if it is for a simple motion design, it is easier to use shape keys. And yes, the door can be complex, as long as you can transform the initial wireframe to a desired shape.

Comment: Well it's really a door. What I am trying to achieve is a CAD-like (very simple of course) program (in BabylonJS) that allow user to positioning and sizing (with constraint like the door) the furniture in a house. Animation is not what I'm looking for the moment but it looks like it's the solution.

Comment: @QuangLinhLe If it is for architecture modeling, use Archipack or Archimesh add-ons. Blender natively does not have a CAD-like constraints toolset. It is not suited for engineering. It is more of an artistic software. Why did you use bones in the first place?

Comment: @QuangLinhLe I think that a CAD-like behavior is achieved with parametric modeling, not with animated deformation with bones. You can create some in Blender with http://nortikin.github.io/sverchok/, but in your case, it should be an in-app implementation.

Comment: Hello @unwave, I have follow your example and it's working great for me. What I am doing is to create multiple pieces (for example, a sliding door) and then depend on the ratio of the size of the pieces, the transformation of the pieces should be added accordingly. This way, I'm still be able to transform the door but also be able to slide it. Thank you for the detail answer (and comment.)